# How to clear the Output message on a Submit button click using JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, validation

Hi Everyone out there..!!

I'm Facing a serious issue on clearing the retrieved message.

**Flow of My project:**

- I'm having four text boxes and one submit button in my .aspx page.
- And the four text boxes are required field.
- If i give values in all the text boxes and click submit button i am getting the desired output.

This is the flow of my project.

**Problem:**

- Now the problem is i don't have clear button in my screen.
- I just clear a value from one of the text box and now I am clicking submit button.
- It throws the required field validator error message as expected.
- But the output from the previous execution is not getting cleared in this click event.

**Expected:**

I want the required field validator to throw the error and also the Output i got from the previous execution should be cleared.

This is the code i have tried

```
<script> 
function hide()
 { 
document.getElementById('pnlResult').style.display = 'none';
 }
 </script>
```

I have tried this script in **submit** button `OnClientClick()` event

the problem in this is i have set `required field validator` for all the text but there is no value in one of the text box but it does execution and fetches me the result that

```
 "no record is found"
```

Actually since one of the text box field is empty it should not do the execution at all.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p4as6/10/

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />

Answer (score 1):

You need to Put your result in particular panel and then you can hide the panel.

```
<script>
    function hide() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=textbox1.ClientID%>").value == "" || document.getElementById("<%=textbox3.ClientID%>").value == "" || document.getElementById("<%=textbox3.ClientID%>").value == "" || document.getElementById("<%=textbox4.ClientID%>").value == "") {
           var panel = document.getElementById("<%= pnlResult.ClientID%>");
            if (panel) {
                document.getElementById("<%=pnlResult.ClientID%>").style.display = 'none';
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Now you need to call this script in submit Button Onclientclick

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs